# Why is webpack bundling my orphaned code?

Tags: typescript, webpack

I have a Library and a Project. The Library is compiled using `tsc`, it's not bundled. Project is bundled using webpack. There are some unused exports (e.g. `ag-grid-wrapper` in the example below from Library (along with their transitive dependencies) that are still bundled into my app.js.

I have a project structure like this:

```
/
/lib
/lib/src/ag-grid-wrapper.ts
/lib/src/some-function.ts
/lib/src/index.ts
/lib/package.json
/project
/project/src/app.ts
/project/package.json
/project/webpack.config.json
```

/lib/src/index.ts:

```
export { createWrappedGrid } from "./ag-grid-wrapper";
export { myFunction } from "./some-function";
```

/project/package.json:

```
...
"dependencies": {
  "lib": "../lib/"
...
```

/project/src/app.ts:

```
import { myFunction } from "lib";
```

/project/webpack.config.json:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: "./src/app.ts",
  module: { rules: [{ test: /\.tsx?$/, use: ["ts-loader"], exclude: /node_modules/ }] },
  resolve: { extensions: [".tsx", ".ts", ".js" },
  output { filename: "app.js" }
};
```

Isn't webpack meant to optimise `ag-grid-wrapper.ts` and its dependencies out of the final app.js?

Using the latest version of webpack.